# Traversing along guided path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var distancesquared = (transform.position - currentpath.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
if (distancesquared < 0.1f * 0.1f)
    currentpath.MoveNext ();
```

I have created a path to be followed using an array of Transforms in unity, now If I do not use the above if statement and just do `currentpath.MoveNext()`, it just traverses along first pair of points and does not go one beyond to complete the path, what is the co relation of this if statement with traversing the path, Please?

**Edit:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class followpath : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum followtype
    {
        movetowards,
        lerp
    }
    public followtype type = followtype.movetowards;
    public Pathdefinition path;
    public float speed = 1;
    public float maxdistancetodo = 0.1f;

    private IEnumerator<Transform>  currentpath;
    public void Start()
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError ("path can not be null", gameObject);
            return;
        }
        currentpath = path.getpathenumerator ();
        currentpath.MoveNext ();
        if (currentpath.Current == null)
            return;

        transform.position = currentpath.Current.position;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (currentpath == null || currentpath.Current == null)
            return;
        if (type == followtype.movetowards)
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, currentpath.Current.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        else if (type == followtype.lerp)
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, currentpath.Current.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);


        var distancesquared = (transform.position - currentpath.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (distancesquared < maxdistancetodo* maxdistancetodo)
            currentpath.MoveNext ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? Just putting in your condition isn't really helping. Oh, and you can replace `0.1f * 0.1f` with just `0.01f`

Comment: @NickUdell: I just did :)

Comment: Couple of comments, from a C# perspective (it looks to me like you're coming from a Java perspective), Get methods are rarely used in C#, and Properties are preferred, additionally instead of an enumerator, you might consider using the Queue datatype, which encapsulates what you want to do better (unless you want to be able to reverse a path or something later, of course).

Answer (score 1):

When you put code in update, it executes every frame.

The if statement checks to make sure your object is near enough to it's current target position before iterating to the next target point in the path.

Without your if statement, each frame will cause the next stop on the path to be loaded in the iterator. This occurs before your object has had a chance to get near its previous target. Additionally, since frames occur so quickly, it means the entire path is iterated over in less than a second, and the object stops moving before it's managed to go very far.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I got your point that the target will be loaded before it had a chance to go close enough to it, but "Entire path is loaded in less than a second", The object should not stop to move because the transform points are actually in a loop in this case so it is always receiving the transform to traverse on

Comment: Sadly, nobody would be able to tell that the path is in a loop because you have not shown us the path.GetEnumerator() function, so I assumed a list or queue.

Comment: @I am sorry, by that I meant that supply of transform points i.e it first goes from end to other and from that end to back again. Like in Mario, remember how the platforms kept on moving continuously?I am doing that using these transform points.