# Unity 2D error 1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble with the below code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FollowPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum FollowType
    {
        MoveTowards,
        Lerp
    }

    public FollowType Type = FollowType.MoveTowards;
    public PathDefinition Path;
    public float Speed = 1;
    public float MaxDistanceToGoal = .1f;

    private IEnumerator<Transform> _currentPoint;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Path == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Path cannot be null", gameObject);
            return;
        }

        _currentPoint = Path.GetPathEnumerator();
        _currentPoint.MoveNext();

        if (_currentPoint.Current == null)
            return;

        transform.position = _currentPoint.Current.position;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (_currentPoint == null || _currentPoint.Current == null)
            return;

        if (Type == FollowType.MoveTowards)
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position,
                    _currentPoint.Current.position, Time.deltaTime * Speed);
        else if (Type == FollowType.Lerp)
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,
                    _currentPoint.Current.position, Time.deltaTime * Speed);

        var distanceSquared = (transform.position -
                _currentPoint.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (distanceSquared < MaxDistanceToGoal * MaxDistanceToGoal)
            _currentPoint.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Assets/Code/FollowPath.cs(28,36): error CS1061: Type `PathDefinition' does not contain a definition for`GetPathEnumerator' and no extension method `GetPathEnumerator' of type`PathDefinition' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where did you get the type PathDefinition from? There is none to be found in Unity3D documentation... Either way, it obviously doesn't contain a definition of `GetPathEnumerator`...

Comment: FWIW, this code was also [posted Feb 12 on unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/899757/can-someone-help-me-with-this-problem.html) with no responses.

Comment: @cod3monk3y, yes, I've found it on multiple places as well, no responses as well.. It's weird, cause I can't find that PathDefinition type anywhere, so it's pretty puzzling to me how are we supposed to answer this with so few info provided..

Comment: In what looks to be the original post, user [Mark Udell recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717760/traversing-along-guided-path#comment38971880_24717760) using something other than an iterator to define your path. I agree, especially since you don't actually have the `PathDefinition` code. Maybe this comes from a Unity plugin somewhere, though. Try and track that down?

Comment: Found it! The YouTube video [Creating 2D Games in Unity 4.5 #4 - Moving Platforms by 3DBuzz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkGPoZOQE5Q) appears to be where the source comes from. A comment from user 26dollar appears to have transcribed the code. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

This missing code appears to originate from a 3DBuzz youtube video [Creating 2D Games in Unity 4.5 #4 - Moving Platforms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkGPoZOQE5Q). User 26dollar transcribed the code, which I auto-formatted and reproduce here:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

public class PathDefinition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] Points;

    public IEnumerator<Transform> GetPathEnumerator()
    {
        if (Points == null || Points.Length < 1)
            yield break;

        var direction = 1;
        var index = 0;
        while (true) {
            yield return Points[index];

            if (Points.Length == 1)
                continue;

            if (index <= 0)
                direction = 1;
            else if (index >= Points.Length - 1)
                direction = -1;

            index = index + direction;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (Points == null || Points.Length < 2)
            return;

        for (var i = 1; i < Points.Length; i++) {
            Gizmos.DrawLine(Points[i - 1].position, Points[i].position);
        }
    }
}
```